# Logging from APIs built with multiple platforms

Tags: logging, cross-platform, asp.net-web-api

I have an number of HTTP APIs, some are built using C# Web API, some are built using Node.js, and it is quite possible that other apis will be build using yet another technology. I would like to have a central logging service, such that each request to these apis is logged. Ideally, the APIs would simply throw some packet at the logging service, and they wouldn't really wait for a confirmation. For instance, a message filter could be built for the C# Web APIs, and this filter would send a packet to this central service (possibly by using UDP).

Does anyone know of a service which is capable of this? I.e. cross platform logging service?